# Breaking an array and create new array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array `$data`

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 049-1090
            [color] => Beige,Brown
            [Finish] => Distressed,Handscraped,Matt
            [Grade] => B (Select/Advantage)
            [Installation Location] => Second Floor,Main Floor
            [Installation Method] => Nail Down
            [Specie] => Maple
            [Warranty] => 25 Years
            [Width] => 5 inch
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 107-1079
            [color] => Brown,Yellow
            [Edge] => Square Edge
            [Finish] => Matt
            [Grade] => B (Select/Advantage)
            [Installation Location] => Second Floor,Main Floor
            [Installation Method] => Glue Down,Nail Down
            [Specie] => Maple
            [Warranty] => 25 Years
            [Width] => 3 5/8 inch
        )
    )
```

Now I want to create an array `$final_array` which will contain only 2 keys. First key is `sku` and second key is `feature`. `feature` key will consist of the values of all of the keys other than `sku` exploding the values at `,` so the final array will look like:

```
    (
    [sku]=>049-1090
    [feature]=>color:Beige
)
 (
    [sku]=>049-1090
    [feature]=>color:Brown
)
(
    [sku]=>049-1090
    [feature]=>Finish:Distressed
)
(
    [sku]=>049-1090
    [feature]=>Finish:Handscraped
)
(
    [sku]=>049-1090
    [feature]=>Finish:Matt
)
```

And so on for the second `sku`

I have tried like this:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($data as $value){

   foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){

            $final_array[] = ['sku'=>$innerkey,'feature'=>$innervalue];

   }

}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($data as $value){
   $sku = $value['sku'];
   foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue){
       if ($innerkey!='sku') {
            $subvalues = explode(',', $innervalue);
            foreach ($subvalues as $subvalue) {
                 $final_array[] = ['sku'=>$sku,'feature'=>$innerkey . ':' . $subvalue];
            }
       }
   }

}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, its partially correct. But i also need to explode the values separated by comma into array. For example `[color] => Beige,Brown` will have 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

By making a few minor edits to my answer on your previous question, this task can be accomplished without iterated conditionals.

Temporarily cache the sku then remove it from the row of data, this way you can swiftly explode and iterate all of the remaining data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XPJm4))

```
$final_array = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $sku = $row['sku'];
    unset($row['sku']);
    foreach ($row as $featureName => $featureValues) {
        foreach (explode(',', $featureValues) as $featureValue) {
            $final_array[] = [
                'sku' => $sku,
                'feature' => "{$featureName}:{$featureValue}"
            ];
        }
    }
}
var_export($final_array);
```